# How to sort data using buttons in Codeigniter and Bootstrap

Tags: php, sorting, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

So, in this case, I have a list of hotel rooms, and I want to display each data like a square view, using bootstrap of course.

The problem is, how to sort the data according to the order of the numeric values?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0EKC.png)

Example :
21 35 2

Become :
2 21 35

Views.php

```
  <section class="content"> 
   <h2>Gate A</h2>
   <div class="card ml-1" style="width: 35rem">
    <div class="row ml-3 mt-3 mb-3">

     <?php
       foreach ($tamu as $tamu_item) : 
     ?>

     <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
       <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mb-1"><?php echo $tamu_item->gateA ?> 
        </button>
      </div>  
    </div>
      <?php endforeach;?> 
  </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Could you provide input example please ? So we should understand problem easily.

Comment: For Example, if input : 21 35 2
else
 Become : 2 21 35. Be sequential

Comment: Use `sort()` function from documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php